# What is the difference among "niebla", "neblina" and "bruma"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

All three seem to mean fog or mist. Is there any regional difference in usage? Or do they actually stand for slightly different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that their difference is mainly **visibility**. If you can see something (fairly well) it might be *neblina*. If you can't see much is *niebla*. I don't know if this "threshold" for visibility is subjective or not, but I'm positive that the *niebla* is "thicker" than the *neblina*, allowing you to see less. Most famous example I can think of is "La niebla de Londres" (is there a difference in English between *mist* and *fog*?)

Then, the *bruma* is when those water drops that form the mist are over or near the sea.

I don't know if there are any regional difference in usage, but they might depend on wether that place is close or not to the sea or ocean (using *bruma* more often than the other, or instead of them).

Comment: DRAE says about bruma "Niebla, y especialmente la que se forma sobre el mar."

Comment: This agrees completely with RAE. **Niebla** is a very low cloud that affects visibility and it becomes **neblina** when it is low density since neblina is the diminutive of niebla.

Comment: In English fog is thicker than mist.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Wikipedia entry for [neblina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neblina) the difference is in the visibility and the size of droplets. *Niebla* has visibility less than 1 km, *nieblina* 1 to 10 km. The relative humidity is between 90 to 100 and 80 to 90 respectively. The English equivalents are fog and mist. *Calima* and *Bruma* involve solid particles with visibility > 2km and < 2 km respectively. I think the English equivalent is haze although severe cases are called smog.

Edited in response to @Gorpik's comment below

There is an international definition of fog and mist available from the World Meteorological Organization web-site [here](http://www.caem.wmo.int/_pdf/low_cloud_visibility/lowcloudvis_04_mist_fog.pdf) which is what the Wikipedia entry is using.

Comment: Great discovery! I did not know such vocabulary was regulated that much.

Comment: Nice find, but that Wikipedia table is not referenced and offers some dubious data (according to it, visibility with *llovizna* is less than with *lluvia*, and the article on *bruma* itself claims that it involves water, not solid particles as *calima*).

Comment: @Gorpik it seems that fog versus mist is an international definition as the English entry for fog has a reference to a book which in turn cites the World Meteorological Office.

Comment: Yep, it looks like that one is generally accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the same in all Mexico but here we just say "niebla" or "neblina", no difference at all, and no one says "bruma".

Comment: Which part of Mexico would that be if you don't mind telling?

Comment: South of Veracruz.