# ¿Cuál es la palabra que se usa para referirse a un día que tiene mucha neblina?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

Cuando un día tiene mucho sol está soleado, cuando tiene muchas nubes está nublado, ¿y cuando tiene mucha neblina?

Comment: You might also be interested in this Q&A http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/what-is-the-difference-among-niebla-neblina-and-bruma/19134#19134

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> neblinoso, sa.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho del día o de la atmósfera: En que abunda y es baja la niebla.
>
> Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados

[Enlace](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=QJtF1G3)

Comment: brumoso es sinónimo o es otra cosa?

Answer (score 3):

Como ha dicho Julio, "neblinoso" es el adjetivo para una atmósfera con mucha neblina.
Ante tu duda de "brumoso", éste se usa cuando hay mucha bruma, que la RAE lo define como:

> **[bruma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6BB5hPp)**
>
> Del lat. *bruma* 'solsticio de invierno'.
>
> 1. f. Niebla, y especialmente la que se forma sobre el mar.
> 2. f. desus. invierno (‖ estación del año).
>
> <sub>Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados</sub>

Otro sinónimo, podría ser "nebuloso" en el caso de que quieras hablar de que hay mucha niebla. Todo depende del matiz entre niebla, neblina y bruma.

Comment: Un hallazgo curioso: la palabra "bruma" al parecer originariamente designaba al invierno, por su origen latino, para pasar luego a denominar a la niebla.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, yo digo "nublado" a un día con mucha niebla y "nuboso" a un día con muchas nubes en el cielo. Más raramente uso "neblina" para referirme a una niebla débil (como diminutivo). No sé si ésto será *incorrecto* pero en mi entorno es lo más común. Puede que se trate de variaciones regionales en España.